# How to Show Modal until data was ready in ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use modal loading until data come. I try to use beforeSend() to show modal snd complete() to hide modal but it doesn't work. Modal is show but when data are ready modal isn't hide

**this is my button**

```
<a href="Javascript:void(0);" id="LinkUser" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">User</a>
```

**Data will show here in #showTable**

```
<div class="col py-3">
     <div class="container scroll-x" id="showTable">

            
     </div>
     <div class="modal fade loading" id="loading" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loading" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered">
               <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                           Loading....
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

**This is ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#LinkUser').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "usertable.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading').modal('show');
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('#showTable').load('usertable.php');
                // $('#showTable').html(result);
            },
            complete:function(){
                $('#loading').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: where is your beforeSend() and complete()?

Comment: Sorry sir, I edited it